# FFmpeg static keyframe rate

Tags: ffmpeg, keyframe

I have a question about ffmpeg usage. Every time when I trying to convert video files into
some different format, output file getting static keyframe sequence.

What I mean is that keyframes appear at the distance of 12 frames. I know that its controllerd by parameter **-g** that you can change to any other number.

```
ffmpeg -i 1.avi -vcodec mpeg4 -b 2000000  out.avi
```

I believe there should be some way to make keyframes appear on uneven intervals. These interval should be calculated by codec, and it should be based on image changes in the video file. So keyframes should be inserted only when they needed, but not consistently after N frames.

Can somebody please explain to me how this "smart" encoding can be done with ffmpeg ?
Thank you

SOLUTION: ok what I'ev been looking for has very simple solution. If you set -g to zero, ffmpeg will choose keyframes based on the video shots and bitrate

Answer (score 6):

If you set -g to zero, ffmpeg will choose keyframes based on the video shots and bitrate

Comment: Sorry - didn't want to poach your answer, but if I see a question w/o an answer, I tend to bounce w/o reading.